# How to reduce decimals in a POST request

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

My POST request sends output with 3 decimals while wanted is 1

I am unable to understand what I should tweak to send 1 decimal point in the POST requests

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("127.0.0.1:8080")
    for sensor in W1ThermSensor.get_available_sensors():
        print("Sensor %s with id %s  has temperature %.2f" % (sensorNameList.get(sensor.id), sensor.id, sensor.get_temperature()))
        try:
            params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'temperature': sensor.get_temperature()})
            headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
            conn.request("POST", "/WeatherStationServer/api/temperature/"  + sensorNameList.get(sensor.id), params, headers)
```

The output is 23.357 while it should be 23.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the result of `sensor.get_temperature()`, just [`format` it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) to the appropriate width, e.g.:

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'temperature': format(sensor.get_temperature(), '.1f')})
```

An alternative approach (that leaves it a `float`) is to use [the `round` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'temperature': round(sensor.get_temperature(), 1)})
```

For a case where an actual string is required, I'd recommend formatting it explicitly (as libraries that format a `float` might not follow Python's rules for formatting, and might end up supplying additional decimal places).

Note that the correct rounding for both cases produces 23.4, not 23.3. If you really want to truncate, not round, you're stuck being a bit ugly to multiply, truncate, and divide back, e.g.:

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'temperature': round(int(sensor.get_temperature() * 10) / 10, 1)})
```

Since converting to `int` explicitly removes trailing decimal places, this will compute the following values:

1. After multiplication `233.57`
2. After `int` conversion, `233`
3. After division, `23.3`
4. After `round` (necessary to handle cases where floating point imprecision might make dividing by 10 produce more than one decimal point): `23.3`

Comment: Thank you very much, one decimal point for the temperatures I need doesn't make a difference, so I will go with your first proposal :)